# How to combine two tfidf sparse vectors

Tags: scikit-learn, tf-idf

Say that I have two document collections that I have created a tf-idf sparse vector for each one using TfidfVectorizer. How could I combine those two vectors into one that would resemble the tfidf of the union of the two collection?

How could I approach this since the two collection will probably have different features?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you calculate them from scratch?

An important part of the Vector Space Model is the dictionary. In your case you are having two collections and therefore two dictionaries that may have common elements or may not. In any case you need to merge the two dictionaries and then calculate TF-IDF weights for each of your documents.

Otherwise I don't see what semantics merging would have in a different dimensional space.

Comment: I see. A full tf-idf recalculation is not an option since it would take a lot of time. What if I used a pre-made dictionary for both of those vectors. What could be done in that instance?

Comment: @MarkosdiMitsas Yes but you should be careful to maintain the correct positioning for the corresponding frequencies after merging. For example if initially the dictionary was T1 T2 T3 and then for the 2nd collection T4 T5 T6 and you end up with T1 T4 T2 T3 T5 T6, you are messing with the first collection's vectors as they are not still the same thing as initially captured.

Comment: I think positioning shouldn't be a problem since sklearn makes sure to keep them intact. But the problem is how could I refresh both vectors with the unions idf?

Comment: If I used CountVectorizer in both document sets, then unite both matrices and run it through TfidfTransformer  would it work? Also would it work fast? I should try it.

Comment: @MarkosdiMitsas The bottom line is that I don't think you can simply merge all of the results as documents from collection 2 for example have never seen terms from collection 1 and therefore have to re-calculate the weights.

Comment: Well of course. A partial re-calculation is needed of course. What I meant before was that I don't want to calculate the whole tf-idf of the collection. I think I only need to calculate the idf's since tf could be precalculated